# how to set the expiry of the redis keys in golang

Tags: go, redis

I am using golang as my backend.I am storing some token values in redis.I m setting the values HSET and getting the values in HGETALL.I would like to know if there is any function to set the expiry for the keys that i m storing in the redis database.i want the token and its data to be deleted after 1hour. I m using Redigo package for redis. Thanks.Appreciate any help.

```
I use this to set the struct with has token as key    
redisCon.Do("HMSET", redis.Args{}.Add(hashToken).AddFlat(&dataStruct)...)
```

Comment: you should tell others what redis library you use. And also you can search about how to use it in "godoc.com"

Comment: I use redigo library in my client side to connect with the redigo server..and i use like this c.Do("HMSET", ciphertext, 3200, datastruct).Here cipertext is the key,3200 is ttl,datastruct is the struc that contains the details of the token.But checking ttl for that key it shows -1...Appreciate any help.Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Redis documentation](http://redis.io/commands/hmset) does not support a command like "HMSETEX".
"HMSET" modifies the hashkeys and not the root key. TTL is supported at root key level and not at the hash key level. Hence, in your case you must be doing something like this in a separate call:

```
redisCon.Do("EXPIRE", key, ttl)
```

Which client are you using to connect to redis?

For redigo you can use this - https://github.com/yadvendar/redigo-wrapper
In that use call

```
func Expire(RConn *redigo.Conn, key string, ttl int)
```

For goredis - https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/redis.v5#Client.TTL
In this use:

```
func (c *Client) TTL(key string) *DurationCmd
```

Comment: Thanks.the expiry time is set only when i set separately . But when i combine both in hset and when i check the ttl using the key it shows -1.May i know what went wrong here.I used something like this c.Do("HMSET", ciphertext, 3200, datastruct).For your info  datastruct is the token struct that have some fields in it.Thanks Appreciate any help...

Comment: Setting it separately as two calls may be best if it's working for you. If you're not committed to the package you're using it might be worth it to check out this package https://github.com/keimoon/gore/wiki/Pipeline.. With the pipeline tool you can set up calls and run them in tandem. So set then expire.

Comment: You need to set it separately only. As per Redis's official documentation it supports "SETEX" http://redis.io/commands/setex - setting string data as value and expiry to a given key. It does not support any "HMSETEX" command, so I think you need to call that separately only.

Answer (score 11):

For those who use `go-redis` library, you can set expiration by calling

```
_, err = redisClient.Expire("my:redis:key", 1 * time.Hour).Result()
```

Alternatively, you can do that upon insertion

```
_, err = redisClient.Set("my:redis:key", "value", 1 * time.Hour).Result()
```

Comment: it says invalid time expiration

Comment: @chovy which redis version are you using? is this the exact error you got "invalid time expiration"? what's the value in seconds you tried to set?

Comment: I wasn't using `time.Hour` i guess that's required. I was just passing `86400` and i guess that's nanoseconds too so it was expiring right away.