# How to specify go-redis expires

Tags: go, redis

I'm using go-redis, I want to specify expires, how can I do it?

The library I'm using is "github.com/go-redis/redis/v8"

redis url environment

```
case "redis":
    // URL for Redis connection.
    url = fmt.Sprintf(
        "redis://%s:%s@%s:%s/%s",
        os.Getenv("REDIS_USER"),
        os.Getenv("REDIS_PASSWORD"),
        os.Getenv("REDIS_HOST"),
        os.Getenv("REDIS_PORT"),
        os.Getenv("REDIS_DATABASE"),
    )
```

---

redis link function

```
var (
    RDBConn *redis.Client
)

func InitRedis() {
    url, _ := config.ConnectionURLBuilder("redis")

    opt, err := redis.ParseURL(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Connection Error")
        panic(err)
    }

    // redis session expires after 30 minutes of inactivity
    

    RDBConn = redis.NewClient(opt)

    fmt.Println("Connected to redis server")
}
```

Comment: Typically the goal is to expire data stored in redis. Your example doesn't show how you're setting a value, but something like this would do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40674920/how-to-set-the-expiry-of-the-redis-keys-in-golang . It seems you want to end the session after 30 minutes. I'm curious why you need to do that. But I guess you would do something like set a timer and unset that client so it can't be reused. Or better yet, exit this routine.